# Read properties file without using Key

Tags: spring, jsp, properties-file

I have a property file without Key and only content and I want to display the content of property file in jsp Page after escaping html tags. How to do this?

property file:

```
Here is an example of content, messages. <p>

<b>approach<b> <br>
<a href="www.google.com">Find out more about our website</a>
</p>
```

How can I display this in jsp Page using spring? Any help?

Comment: Please show your file structure

Comment: message.properties: <p>
<b>approach<b> <br>
<a href="www.google.com">Find out more about our website</a>
</p>

Answer (score 0):

message.properties is typically used for internationalization. Usually properties file in general is used for small value(s) and plain text.

For your case, I'd just create a separate jsp file and include it in your jsp.

`<%@ include file="aboutus.jsp" %>`